# Passing the value of a textfield to a function on CocoaTouch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following code on the .h file:

```
@interface ComposeViewController : UIViewController {
    id  delegate;
    IBOutlet UITextField *notificationTitle;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (void)scheduleAlert;
@end
```

And on the .m file

```
- (void)scheduleAlert {
        // open an alert with just an OK button
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:(@"Hi") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        [alert release];
}
```

I want to put the content of the `NSString *notificationTitle` on the message propietry of the `*alert`. If I pass using that code it crashes

```
- (void)scheduleAlert {
        // open an alert with just an OK button
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:(@"%@", notificationTitle)
                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

How I may pass the `*notificationTitle` to `*alert` message?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" 
                          message:notificationTitle
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

or

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" 
                          message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is the string: %@", notificationTitle]
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

for UIText field, you should use its `text` property like this

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:notificationTitle.text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```